# accumulatedweight throws cv:Exception error

Tags: image-processing, opencv

I am new to OpenCV and trying to find contours and draw rectangle on them, here's my code but its throwing cv::Exception when it comes to **accumulatedweighted()**.

```
#include "opencv2/video/tracking.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc_c.h"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"

#include <iostream>
#include <ctype.h>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

static void help()
{
cout << "\nThis is a Example to implement CAMSHIFT to detect multiple motion objects.\n";
}

Rect rect;
VideoCapture capture;
Mat currentFrame, currentFrame_grey, differenceImg, oldFrame_grey,background;
vector<vector<Point> > contours;
vector<Vec4i> hierarchy;

bool first = true;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
//Create a new movie capture object.
capture.open(0);

if(!capture.isOpened())
{
    //error in opening the video input
    cerr << "Unable to open video file: " /*<< videoFilename*/ << endl;
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}   

//capture current frame from webcam
capture >> currentFrame;

//Size of the image.
CvSize imgSize;
imgSize.width = currentFrame.size().width; //img.size().width
imgSize.height = currentFrame.size().height; ////img.size().height

//Images to use in the program.
currentFrame_grey.create( imgSize, IPL_DEPTH_8U);//image.create().  

while(1)
{
    capture >> currentFrame;//VideoCapture& VideoCapture::operator>>(Mat& image)                

    //Convert the image to grayscale.
    cvtColor(currentFrame,currentFrame_grey,CV_RGB2GRAY);//cvtColor()

    // Converting Original image to make both background n original image same
    currentFrame.convertTo(currentFrame,CV_32FC3);
    background = Mat::zeros(currentFrame.size(), CV_32FC3);

    //Here its throwing exception
    accumulateWeighted(currentFrame,background,1.0,NULL);

    imshow("Background",background);

    if(first) //Capturing Background for the first time
    {
        differenceImg = currentFrame_grey.clone();//img1 = img.clone()
        oldFrame_grey = currentFrame_grey.clone();//img2 = img.clone()
        convertScaleAbs(currentFrame_grey, oldFrame_grey, 1.0, 0.0);//convertscaleabs()
        first = false;
        continue;
    }

    //Minus the current frame from the moving average.
    absdiff(oldFrame_grey,currentFrame_grey,differenceImg);//absDiff()

    //bluring the differnece image
    blur(differenceImg, differenceImg, imgSize);//blur()

    //apply threshold to discard small unwanted movements
    threshold(differenceImg, differenceImg, 25, 255, CV_THRESH_BINARY);//threshold()

    //find contours
    findContours(differenceImg,contours,hierarchy,CV_RETR_TREE, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE, Point(0, 0)); //findcontours()

    //draw bounding box around each contour
    //for(; contours! = 0; contours = contours->h_next)
    for(int i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++)
    {
        rect = boundingRect(contours[i]); //extract bounding box for current contour
        //drawing rectangle
        rectangle(currentFrame, cvPoint(rect.x, rect.y), cvPoint(rect.x+rect.width, rect.y+rect.height), cvScalar(0, 0, 255, 0), 2, 8, 0);                 
    }       

    //New Background
    convertScaleAbs(currentFrame_grey, oldFrame_grey, 1.0, 0.0);

    //display colour image with bounding box
    imshow("Output Image", currentFrame);//imshow()

    //display threshold image
    imshow("Difference image", differenceImg);//imshow()

    //clear memory and contours
    //cvClearMemStorage( storage );
    //contours = 0;
    contours.clear();

    //background = currentFrame;

    //press Esc to exit
    char c = cvWaitKey(33);
    if( c == 27 ) break;

}

// Destroy All Windows.
destroyAllWindows();

return 0;
}
```

Please Help to solve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I don't really get the idea of calling `accumulateWeighted` with alpha = 1.0. If you look at the definition of accumulateWeighted in the doc, you will see that with alpha = 1.0 it is basically equivalent to copy currentFrame into background at each iteration.

Moreover, it is an accumulation function, to accumulate image changes over time into a new image. What is the interest of it if you reset background at every loop with `background = Mat::zeros(currentFrame.size(), CV_32FC3);` ?

This being said, there is a little flaw in your code with the 4th argument of the function. You wrote `accumulateWeighted(currentFrame,background,1.0,NULL);`. If you look into the [documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/motion_analysis_and_object_tracking.html%20documentation) you will find that the 4th argument is a Mask, and is optional. Passing a NULL pointer here might be the source of your exception. Why don't you call the function like this : `accumulateWeighted(currentFrame,background,1.0);` ?

Hope this helps,

Ben